# How to update batch file from UNC path when the batch file is in use

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, xcopy

I have a batch file (batch1.bat) that checks for updated version on a UNC share and then runs some commands. However, the issue is I want to update the batch file on the share so future updates get applied to all the users when they run the batch. The issue is the batch file is not updated as its running when it checks.

Example:

```
mkdir C:\program\Tools
xcopy /D /Y /e "\\UNC_Share\program\*.*" "C:\program\"
```

This copies the batch file to Tools folder.

I created a new file called update.bat, and it calls the above xcopy command and then opens the original batch file (batch1.bat) to do its thing. However, can't figure out how to get the batch1.bat to call the update, close and reopen the batch without calling the update in a loop.

1. User opens (runs) batch1.bat.
2. Batch1.bat calls update.bat and closes batch1.bat so it can update from the UNC share.
3. Once the update is done update.bat calls batch1.bat, and it runs the tools.

Files on the UNC share

```
\\UNC_Share\program\
    batch1.bat
    update.bat
\\UNC_Share\program\Tools
    some .exe and .dll files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no problem as running a batch file from within a batch file without using command `call` results in stopping processing current batch file and continue the processing on started batch file.

**batch1.bat:**

```
@echo off
rem Set directory of batch file as current working directory.
cd /D "%~dp0"

rem Check if update was already done before. If the environment variable
rem "UpdateDone" defined in batch file update.bat not set, run the update
rem if the batch file for updating exists at all. Pass as parameter the
rem name of this batch file to restart it after the update.
if "%UpdateDone%"=="" if exist "\\UNC_Share\program\update.bat" "\\UNC_Share\program\update.bat" %0

rem Remove the environment variable "UpdateDone" after update processed.
set UpdateDone=

rem Put here any commands which should be executed by this batch file.
echo Batch1 is processing, please wait ...
```

**update.bat:**

```
@echo off
echo Updating tools, please wait ...

rem Target directory automatically created because of switch /I if not exist.
xcopy /D /Y /E /I /Q "\\UNC_Share\program\*" "C:\program\Tools\" 1>nul

rem If there was no argument passed on running this batch file, there
rem is nothing else to do. Otherwise it is expected that the first
rem argument is the name of the batch file which started this batch
rem file for updating the tools and therefore start this batch file
rem now again after setting the environment variable "UpdateDone".
if not "%~1"=="" (
   set UpdateDone=yes
   %1
)
```